# Match words using this regex pattern, only if these words do not appear within a list of substrings

Tags: python, regex

```py
import re

input_text = "a áshgdhSdah saasas a corrEr, assasass a saltó sasass a sdssaa" #example

list_verbs_in_this_input = ["serías", "serían", "sería", "ser", "es", "corré", "corrió", "corría", "correr", "saltó", "salta", "salto", "circularías", "circularía", "circulando", "circula", "consiste", "consistían", "consistía", "consistió", "ladró", "ladrando", "ladra", "visualizar", "ver", "vieron", "vió"]

noun_pattern = r"((?:\w+))" # pattern that doesnt tolerate whitespace in middle

imput_text = re.sub(r"(?:^|\s+)a\s+" + noun_pattern, 
                    "\(\g<0>\)", 
                    input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

I need the regex to identify and replace a substring containing no whitespaces in between `"((?:\w+))"` when it is at the beginning of the line or preceded by "a", `"(?:^|\s+)a\s+"`, only if `"((?:\w+))"` does not match any of the strings that are inside the list `list_verbs_in_this_input` or a dot `.` , using a regex pattern similar to this `re.compile(r"(?:" + rf"({'|'.join(list_verbs_in_this_input)})" + r"|[.;\n]|$)", flags = re.IGNORECASE)`

And the **correct output** should look like this:

```
'(áshgdhSdah) saasas a corrEr, assasass a saltó sasass (sdssaa)'
```

Note that the substrings `"a corrEr"` and `"a saltó"` were not modified, since they contained substring(words) that are in the `list_verbs_in_this_input` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude some words, you can use a negative look ahead assertion when at the start of the word you're about to match.

A few things to correct:

- `re.sub` takes the flags as 5<sup>th</sup> argument, not 4<sup>th</sup>
- `"\("` is not an escape sequence, so you should just do `"(\g<0>)"` without "escaping" the parentheses -- they have no special meaning in that string.
- `r"(?:^|\s+)a\s+"` will always *require* the `a` to be there. From your description I understood that the `a` could be optional when the word is at the start of a line, so `r"(?:\ba\s|^)\s*"`
- In the regex that should match the forbidden words, make sure to require that the word **ends** right after the match, so add `\b` in the pattern.

Here is what you could do:

```
import re

input_text = "a áshgdhSdah saasas a corrEr, assasass a saltó sasass a sdssaa" #example

list_verbs_in_this_input = ["serías", "serían", "sería", "ser", "es", "corré", "corrió", "corría", "correr", "saltó", "salta", "salto", "circularías", "circularía", "circulando", "circula", "consiste", "consistían", "consistía", "consistió", "ladró", "ladrando", "ladra", "visualizar", "ver", "vieron", "vió"]

noun_pattern = r"\w+"
exclude = rf"(?!\b(?:{'|'.join(list_verbs_in_this_input)})\b)"
article = r"(?:\ba\s|^)\s*"
regex = article + exclude + noun_pattern

input_text = re.sub(regex, "(\g<0>)", input_text, flags=re.I|re.U)

print(repr(input_text))
```